# How to handle POST requests which result in creating interdependent different resources in Spring?

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, post

I'm currently building a HATEOAS/HAL based REST application with Spring MVC and JPA (Hibernate). Basically the application gives access to a database and allows data retrieval/creation/manipulation.

So far I've already got a lot of things done including a working controller for one of the resources, let's call it *x*.

But I don't want to give the API user the opportunity to create just an *x* resource, because this alone would be useless and could be deleted right away. He/she also has to define a new *y* and a *z* resource to make things work. So: Allowing to create all those resources independently would not break anything but maybe produce dead data like a *z* resource floating around without any connection, completely invisible und useless to the user.

**Example:** I don't want the user to create a new customer without directly attaching a business contract to the customer. (Two different resources: */customers* and */contracts*).

I did not really find any answers or best practice on the web, except for some sort of *bulk POSTing*, but only to one resource, where you would *POST* a ton of customers at once.

Now the following options come to my mind:

1. Let the user create the resources as he/she wants. If there are customers created and never connected to a contract - I don't care. The logic here would be: Allow the user to create */customers* (and return some sort of id, of course). Then if he/she wants to *POST* a new */contract* later I would check if the customer's id given exists and if it does: create the contract.
2. Expect the user, when *POSTing* to */customers*, to also include contract data.

*Option 1* would be the easiest way (and maybe more true to REST?).
*Option 2* is a bit more complicated, since the user does not send single resources any more.

Currently, the controller method for adding a customer starts like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public HttpEntity<Customers> addCustomer(@RequestBody Customers customer) {
    //stuff...
}
```

This way the JSON in the RequestBody would directly fit in my customers class and I can continue working with it. Now with two (or more) expected resources included in the RequestBody this cannot be done the same way any more. Any ideas on how to handle that in a nice way?
I could create some sort of wrapper class (like CustomersContracts), that consists of customers and contract data and has the sole purpose of storing this kind of data in it. But this seems ugly.

I could also take the raw JSON in the RequestBody, parse it and then manually create a customer and a contract object from it, save the customer, get its id and attach it to the contract.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to here after a couple of months. I finally decided to create some kind of wrapper resource (these are example class names):

```
public class DataImport extends ResourceSupport implements Serializable {
    /* The classes referenced here are @Entitys */
    private Import1 import1;
    private Import2 import2;
    private List<Import3> import3;
    private List<Import4> import4;
}
```

So the API user always has to send an Import1 and Import2 JSON object and an Import3 and Import4 JSON array (can also be empty).
In my controller class I do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(*snip*)
public ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestBody DataImport dataImport) {
    Import1 import1 = dataImport.getImport1();
    Import2 import2 = dataImport.getImport2();
    List<Import3> import3 = dataImport.getImport3();
    List<Import4> import4 = dataImport.getImport4();
    // continue...
}
```

I still don't know if it's the best way to do this, but it qorks quite well.